# C - Squaring a integer with value 0 is outputting 1?

Tags: c, zero, pow

```
decPlace_volume = floor(volume+.05) - ceil(volume); //should output -1, 0, or 1
decPlace_volume = pow(decPlace_volume,2); //should the above == -1, this should turn it into 1 while making 0 remain 0
```

The only allowed libraries for my assignment are stdio.h and math.h.

My assignment is pretty simple - find the surface area and volume of a cylinder, and the precision of the output should be 1 unless the output decimal would be 0, in which case the decimal shouldn't be printed.

The above is what I came up with (same thing for surface area just different variables). If the output of the first line is -1, the second line should make it positive, and 0 should stay zero (integer so shouldn't need to worry about funky stuff).

For some reason, when the first line outputs a 0, the second line is outputting 1. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: How do you know that the first line is outputting a 0?

Comment: Also, in what case could the first line output a 1?

Comment: Can you please post how do you know the output is `1` when the first value is `0`, and how do you know that the first  value is `0`?

Comment: decPlace_volume is tied to the precision modifier for the print statement i.e. `printf("The volume is %.*f", decPlace_volume, volume`);`

Comment: First, what is the type  of `decPlace_volume`?  Secondly, under what circumstances can the volume be negative (which is the only way you'll get a -1).  Third, how are you determining the value of `decPlace_volume` at either point?  Are you printing it to the terminal, viewing it in a debugger, what?

Comment: The first line should output a 1 whenever the decimal value of volume is less than .94, otherwise it should print a 0.

Comment: Oh, and by the way ... It's not a very good idea to do `pow(x, 2)`, because it's simply `x * x`, which works regardless of the type of `x`.

Comment: if decimal value is 0.94, how will the first line output 1, it will output -1. (floor(0.99)-ceil(0.94)

Comment: decPlace_volume is an integer. The first line would output -1 when the decimal volume is less than .94.

Comment: Alright fellas thanks for the help, I figured it out. For some reason I thought that my first line could output a 1, but it won't. Instead of `decPlace_volume = pow(decPlace_volume,2);` to convert, I just made a line for `decPlace_volume *= -1;`. Thanks again!

Comment: Question - do you want the output value rounded to the nearest tenth, or just truncated?  IOW, if the value is `1.567`, do you want the output to be `1.5` or `1.6`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks to suppress the decimal if it would be `0`, here is one way to do that

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[25];
    double volume;

    volume = 1.234;
    sprintf (buffer, "%.1f", volume);       // convert to string with 1 place
    if (strstr(buffer, ".0") != NULL)       // examine string
        sprintf (buffer, "%.0f", volume);   // redo the string with 0 places
    printf ("Volume = %s\n", buffer);

    volume = 1.01;
    sprintf (buffer, "%.1f", volume);
    if (strstr(buffer, ".0") != NULL)
        sprintf (buffer, "%.0f", volume);
    printf ("Volume = %s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Volume = 1.2
Volume = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> the precision of the output should be 1 unless the output decimal would be 0, in which case the decimal shouldn't be printed.

OP's approach is subject to problems near multiples of 0.01 due to the typical binary implementation of floating point.  Instead post-processes the output of the unaltered `volume`.

Use `snprintf()`

```
double volume = foo();
char buffer[100];
buffer[0] = 0;
int len = snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%.1f", volume);
if (len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '0') buffer[--len] = '\0';
puts(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright fellas thanks for the help, I figured it out. For some reason I thought that my first line could output a 1, but it won't. Instead of

`decPlace_volume = pow(decPlace_volume,2);`

to convert, I just made a line for `decPlace_volume *= -1;`.

Thanks again!